# Calling a namespaced function by its fully qualified name from inside same namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces, javascript-namespaces, revealing-module-pattern

Is there any reason you would ever want to call a function defined inside a namespace created using the revealing module pattern using its fully qualified name? For example, A vs. B below?

#### Example A.

```
var namespace = (function defineNamespace() {

    function sayNoThankYou() { }

    function callMeMaybe() {
        sayNoThankYou();
    }

    return {
        callMeMaybe: callMeMaybe,
        sayNoThankYou: sayNoThankYou
    };

}());
```

#### Example B.

```
var namespace = (function defineNamespace() {

    function sayNoThankYou() { }

    function callMeMaybe() {
        namespace.sayNoThankYou();
    }

    return {
        callMeMaybe: callMeMaybe,
        sayNoThankYou: sayNoThankYou
    };

}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one difference between `namespace.sayNoThankYou();` and `sayNoThankYou();` in your example: the value of `this` inside the `sayNoThankYou` function. If you don't use `this` inside the function, they are identical.

Comment: Ahh, yes ... thought didn't even cross my mind. I imagine there's no real good way around the need to call `namespace.method()` without `apply` or `call` with this pattern, right? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question is there, but again the same thing would be true: the only difference between using `apply` or `call` or just a direct function call is the value of `this` in the called function. If the function doesn't use `this`, they are all the same.

Comment: I was asking for advice on a way to accomplish having this be the same in the sayNoThankYou function *wihtout* using apply or call, but still using the revealing module pattern. My assumption is there isn't.

Comment: Yeah, the value of `this` is always determined when a function is called. So if you don't call it with `object.method()` or `object['method']()`, you need to use `.call()` or `.apply()`. You *can* hide those inside another function call, as is done for example by Underscore's `_.bind()` function, but that just wraps your original function inside another function that does the `.apply()` for you.